# Running mongodb as as service increases boot time by 30 seconds

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, boot, mongodb

Title says it all. I have an RPi 3 with Raspbian that has a web app running at start up in chromium.  It took 20-30 seconds from powering on to the app appearing before I added mongo, and after I integrated mongo and ran it as a service:

`sudo systemctl enable mongodb`

It increased the bootup time by about 30 seconds.  This isn't really acceptable, so I tried the flat file nosql plugin `tinydb`, and this was a great solution until I realized it wasn't thread or process-safe, which is a requirement here.

Is there any way I can avoid this increase in boot up time?  Some settings I can use for mongo that will disable unnecessary features, another nosql implementation that is lightweight but also thread/process-safe, or some other method of enabling mongo on startup?

Comment: Perhaps have a sleeper process that runs mongodb after a specific amount of time (say, 1 minute)